# .jnlp file won't run (Unknown Source)

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a .jnlp file that wants to run. It shows Unable to Load Resources and then:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Ressource konnte nicht 
geladen werden: URL.jnlp
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 


java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)


at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I upgraded to Java 1.8.0_191 using Windows 7. I'm just trying to get the JNLP file to launch. On another computer user it works, on the domain user runs, on the local user(admin) not. I deleted the temporary files and set the proxy correctly

Comment: This looks like a connectivity/network problem.  Have you attempted to connect to the server/port from the machine you're running the JNLP file, using `nc` or `telnet`?

Comment: Network works well. Maybe it's about access controls. Non-stop attempts to run this file, without effect. The local user has administrator permission.

Comment: i have the same issue most of the times if i use Java version other than jre1.8.0_65 , can you try downgrading?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll try. But everything works on the domain administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the lack of permissions to the folder. The local user having a administrator rights, but did not have the access to the folder.

To change the value and disable UAC:
registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -Value 0

Need reboot to make it take effect.